# How to filter data in an array property for binding in xaml

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, properties

I have a class with the follow field:

```
public byte[] myByteArray;
```

I'm binding the value of the array in a ListView:

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding myByteArray[1]}" />
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding myByteArray[2]}" />
...
```

How can I leave the entry blank when the element in the array is zero?

```
Pseudocode: if(myByteArray[indexValue] == 0) display nothing in ListView
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why does your code said GridViewColumn but your pseudocode say ListView?

Comment: The few examples I based the ListView on used it this way, I don't know the underlining reason, but it works like the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably missing something here, but to make a ListView blank, set it to null.

```
if(myByteArray[indexValue]==0)
   listView=null;
```

To make a specific item blank, set that specific item to null. such as

```
listView.Items.GetItemAt(index)=null;
```

Comment: I think this would set the entire ListView empty. I only want that specific value blank.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not--I ended up finding another way of doing it with data template triggers, thanks anyway for your help.